# How to request authentication from custom middleware in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have two custom ASP.NET Core middlewares: one for authentication (that registers its own authentication scheme) and a second one for some business work.

How can I use the authentication middleware in another middleware? I can use authentication easily in an MVC like that:

```
 services.AddMvc(config =>
 {
     var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                      .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                      .Build();
     config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
 });
```

I can also provide my own `AuthenticationSchemeProvider` to use different authentication schemes based on the requested URL. But the authentication middleware only runs for MVC controllers. I want it to run also before my custom middleware runs. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Here's an example of invoking authz yourself. https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/blob/84c7e3c4c79a334e5a325d971f03fded00555678/samples/StaticFilesAuth/Startup.cs#L151

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In custom middleware method `Invoke()` call `ChallengeAsync()` if user is not authenticated:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await httpContext.ChallengeAsync();
    }
    else { /* logic here */ }
}
```

NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions` has to be added.

Above code will run the default authentication service to authenticate user. If the default one is your custom authentication middleware, then it will be called.

Comment: await httpContext.ChallengeAsync(); was helpful. 
But httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false

Comment: @FemilShajin You may need to add a check on the context.Request.Path depending on which authentication provider you're using. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53088514/net-core-wsfederation-authentication-login-loop-on-localhost/53100821#comment94254608_53100821 for an example.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on `Rython`'s answer for **the specific case of using Windows Authentication**, but also allows designed controllers to use other type of authentication:

```
/// <summary>
/// checks if current request resource can be accesses without being Windows-authenticated
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">http context</param>
/// <returns>true if non-Windows is allowed. Otherwise, false</returns>
public static bool IsAllowedWithoutWindowsAuth(HttpContext context)
{
    bool isAllowedWithoutWindowsAuth = context.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" ||
                                       AllowedControllers.Any(c =>
                                       {
                                           string path = context.Request.Path.ToString();
                                           return path.StartsWith(c, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
                                       });
    return isAllowedWithoutWindowsAuth;
}

// custom middleware code 
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    // anonymous path, skipping
    if (IsAllowedWithoutWindowsAuth(context))
    {
        await _next(context);
        return;
    }

    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync("Windows");
        return;
    }

    // other code here
    await _next(context);
 }
```