# .NET Core WsFederation Authentication login loop on localhost

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I'm trying to implement WsFederation Azure AD authentication into my app, so that users must sign in as soon as they hit the application.  However, when the app starts, it directs to the AAD instance, but then gets stuck in a loop with a blank screen.

My app runs on http://localhost:61213/, in which I've added it as a ReplyUrl in the Azure App Registration dashboard.

Other answers to this suggest that the app should be running over https, however when I've tried to implement those changes, it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I've changed the app to use SSL in VS, so it runs off https instead.  Looping issue still persists.

**Startup.cs**

```
    private void ConfigureAuth(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
                    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                })
            .AddWsFederation(options =>
            {
                options.MetadataAddress =
                    $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{aadTenant}/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml";
                options.Wtrealm = wTrealm;
                options.Wreply = "http://localhost:61213/";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        if (env.IsProduction())
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await context.ChallengeAsync(WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to resolve it - I believe it to be a CORS issue.

```
app.UseCors(policy => policy.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => origin == "https://login.microsoftonline.com"));
app.UseAuthentication();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.Request.Path != "/signin-wsfed")
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync(WsFederationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
});
```

Comment: For me the issue was the missing check for context.Request.Path != "/signin-wsfed". Thanks for coming back with the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this isn't too late but I've experienced a related issue and resolved it by moving the `UseAuthentication` top of `UseMvc` in `Configure` as written in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configuration) (emphasis is mine) :

> In the Configure method, use the `UseAuthentication` method to invoke the Authentication Middleware that sets the `HttpContext.User` property. Call the `UseAuthentication` method **before** calling `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute` or `UseMvc`:

I hope this will avoid the hack of checking **every** request with `context.ChallengeAsync`!